# ClamAV pod not starting in Kubernetes deployed via helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, clamav

I've recently tried to install ClamAV via helm into an existing kubernetes cluster. The install appears successful but when the pod fails to start, logs below.

Would I possibly need to mount a volume and create a file? Or manually create a file in the pod somehow?

**Helm version** 3.2.0

**K8s version** 1.14.10

**ClamAV image**: mailu/clamav:1.6

**ClamAV chart version**: 1.0.5

```
# Helm repo
NAME    URL                                             
stable  https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

# Install via helm
helm install clamav stable/clamav

# Logs from kubernetes pod
Wed May  6 12:52:26 2020 -> ^Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /tmp/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
```

#### ClamAV Deployment

```
Name:                   clamav
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 06 May 2020 13:56:29 +0100
Labels:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=clamav
                        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                        app.kubernetes.io/name=clamav
                        helm.sh/chart=clamav-1.0.5
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        meta.helm.sh/release-name: clamav
                        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:               app.kubernetes.io/instance=clamav,app.kubernetes.io/name=clamav
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app.kubernetes.io/instance=clamav
           app.kubernetes.io/name=clamav
  Containers:
   clamav:
    Image:        mailu/clamav:1.6
    Port:         3310/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Liveness:     tcp-socket :clamavport delay=300s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    tcp-socket :clamavport delay=300s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    True    ReplicaSetUpdated
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   clamav-66fb9687c4 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  38s   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set clamav-66fb9687c4 to 1
```

#### Pod logs

```
Wed May  6 11:46:36 2020 -> ClamAV update process started at Wed May  6 11:46:36 2020
Wed May  6 11:46:36 2020 -> ^Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
Wed May  6 11:46:36 2020 -> ^Local version: 0.100.3 Recommended version: 0.102.2
Wed May  6 11:46:36 2020 -> DON'T PANIC! Read https://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
Wed May  6 11:46:37 2020 -> Downloading main.cvd [100%]
Wed May  6 11:46:50 2020 -> main.cvd updated (version: 59, sigs: 4564902, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Wed May  6 11:46:55 2020 -> Downloading daily.cvd [100%]
Wed May  6 11:49:55 2020 -> daily.cvd updated (version: 25803, sigs: 2358438, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
Wed May  6 11:50:01 2020 -> Downloading safebrowsing.cvd [100%]
Wed May  6 11:50:13 2020 -> safebrowsing.cvd updated (version: 49191, sigs: 2213119, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Wed May  6 11:50:18 2020 -> Downloading bytecode.cvd [100%]
Wed May  6 11:50:18 2020 -> bytecode.cvd updated (version: 331, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
Wed May  6 11:50:30 2020 -> Database updated (9136553 signatures) from database.clamav.net (IP: 104.16.219.84)
Wed May  6 11:50:30 2020 -> ^Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /tmp/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you fix the problem in the meantime? I'm having the same problem